# Метод destroy() у Яндекс.Карт не доступен

Tags: yandex-maps-api

[image: map.destroy() is not a function]

console.log(map.destroy) возвращает, очевидно, undefined, т.к. метода destroy() в объекте карты вообще нет.

API-ключа нет. Может ли быть связано с этим?

Подскажите, что не так?

Откуда идет вызов:

```
    map = new yandexMapInitializer({
        id: 'map',
        data: SDEKStores,
    });

    map.init(function() {
        const list = $('.js-SDEKStores');

        const html = '<li class="Modal__list-item Modal__list-item--first">' +
                        '<span class="total">Всего ' + Object.keys(SDEKStores).length + ' точек самовывоза</span>' +
                     '</li>';

        list.html('');

        list.append(html);

        for (let i in SDEKStores) {
            list.append(generateSDEKStoreItem(SDEKStores[i]));
        }

        // Подставляем в заголовок выбранный пользователем город доставки
        $('.js-cityName').text($('.js-cityToDeliver').val());

        $('#Modal-SDEK').trigger('open');
    });


    map.destroy();
```

Отдельный модуль для карты yandexMapInitializer.js:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'ymaps',
], function($) {

/**
* Инициализирует Яндекс.Карту по заданным параметрам.
*
* @param {string} id Идентификатор карты.
* @param {array} data Содержит массив объектов для инициализации карты.
*/

const yandexMapInitializer = (function(args) {

    function yandexMapInitializer(args) {

        if (!(this instanceof yandexMapInitializer)) {
          return new yandexMapInitializer(args);
        }

        this.id = args.id;
        this.data = args.data;
        this.ymaps = ymaps;
        this.isMobile = args.isMobile || false;
        this.myMap = {};
    }

    yandexMapInitializer.prototype.init = function(callback) {
        const self = this;

        this.ymaps.ready(function() {

            // подготовительные работы
            let bounds     = [[0, 0], [0, 0]];
            let length     = 0;
            /**
             * Переменные для Яндекс.Карты
             */
            let map,
                clusterer,
                coords,
                markerCity,
                pid        = 0,
                sumPointsX = 0,
                sumPointsY = 0;

            for (let i in self.data) {
                const store       = self.data[i];
                const storeCoords = [store.latitude, store.longitude];

                sumPointsX = +store.latitude + +sumPointsX;
                sumPointsY = +store.longitude + +sumPointsY;

                // формирование меток
                store.marker = new ymaps.Placemark(storeCoords, {
                    balloonContent : (store.name ? '<p class="Map__elem-text Map__elem-text--name">' + store.name + '</p>' : '') +
                    (store.address ? '<p class="Map__elem-text Map__elem-text--address">' + store.address + '</p>' : '') +
                    (store.phone ? '<p class="Map__elem-text Map__elem-text--phone">' + store.phone + '</p>' : '') +
                    (store.time ? '<p class="Map__elem-text Map__elem-text--time">' + store.time + '</p>' : '')
                }, {
                    iconLayout      : 'default#image',
                    iconImageHref   : '/app/src/img/map_marker.svg',
                    iconImageSize   : [35, 51],
                    iconImageOffset : [-18, -26],
                });

                // вычисление границ
                if (!bounds[0][0] || bounds[0][0] > storeCoords[0]) bounds[0][0] = storeCoords[0];
                if (!bounds[1][0] || bounds[1][0] < storeCoords[0]) bounds[1][0] = storeCoords[0];
                if (!bounds[0][1] || bounds[0][1] > storeCoords[1]) bounds[0][1] = storeCoords[1];
                if (!bounds[1][1] || bounds[1][1] < storeCoords[1]) bounds[1][1] = storeCoords[1];

                // подсчет кол-ва меток
                length++;
            }

            bounds[0][0] -= 10;
            bounds[0][1] -= 10;
            bounds[1][0] += 10;
            bounds[1][1] += 10;

            // определение центра точек
            const centerPointsX = +sumPointsX / length;
            const centerPointsY = +sumPointsY / length;

            map = new self.ymaps.Map(self.id, {
                center   : [centerPointsX, centerPointsY],
                zoom     : 5,
                controls : ['zoomControl']
            }, {
                minZoom           : 4,
                autoFitToViewport : 'always'
            });

            for (let i in self.data) {
                map.geoObjects.add(self.data[i].marker);
            }


            // вписываем все метки в экран
            map.setBounds(map.geoObjects.getBounds());

            // Блокируем скролл
            map.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }

        });

    }

    return yandexMapInitializer;

})();

return yandexMapInitializer;
```

});

Ссылка на API, которое используем. На проекте стоит requireJS, поэтому подключаем через конфиг и т.д.

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl     : '/app/src/js',
paths       : {
    'jquery'                : '../bower_components/jquery/index',

    ... много разных штук ...

    'ymaps'                 : '//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&mode=debug',
    'yandexMapInitializer'  : './components/yandexMapInitializer'
},
```

Для теста я уже вызываю destroy() прямо после инициализации. И вот такая ошибка вылетает.

**Решение проблемы:**

```
    yandexMapInitializer.prototype.destroy = function() {
        const self = this;

        this.ymaps.ready(function() {
            self.myMap.destroy();
        });
    }
```

Не забываем обернуть вызовы к API Яндекса в ymaps.ready.

Comment: а что за объект map? лучше покажите код

Comment: Добавил код откуда вызов модуля идет и сам модуль карты.

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста для полной картины ссылку на скрипт карт

Comment: Добавил в самый конец вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сейчас вижу что `map` это не объект карты, а Ваш `initializer`.

Внутри него, когда Вы создаете карту, Вы сохряняете ссылку на нее в переменную `map`, которая никуда дальше этого метода не видна.

Сделайте как-то так:

```
this.ymaps.ready(function() {
   ...
   self.myMap = new self.ymaps.Map(
   ...
}
```

и тогда вызов уничтожения можно будет вызвать на этом поле вне `initializer`

```
map.myMap.destroy();
```

а еще лучше сделать метод в `initializer`, который будет это в свою очередь делать, и дергать извне уже этот метод.

Comment: Я вас понял. Спасибо большое, сейчас опишу новый метод в модуле initializer и отпишусь о результате.

Comment: Еще раз благодарю. Вы натолкнули меня на нужное направление. Однако необходимо было в методе destroy() моего модуля Initializer также требовать предварительной загрузки api через функцию ymaps.ready, т.к. иначе функция по-прежнему была undefined (т.к. api не прогрузилось еще).

Comment: @Shadowalker ну и отлично, что разобрались =)